# Building C++11 threadable translation-units in linux

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

Given a simple program that uses C++11 threading features:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void dont_thread_on_me() {
    cout << "action from another thread" << endl;
}

int main() {
    thread t { dont_thread_on_me };
    t.detach();

    cin.get();
}
```

If I build the application using:

```
c++ -std=c++11 Program.cpp -o Program.out
```

the program *builds* fine, but when I run it, I get:

```
./Program.out
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
   what():  Operation not permitted
Aborted
```

If I build it with `-pthread` as in:

```
c++ -std=c++11 Program.cpp -o Program.out -pthread
```

the program executes fine. I haven't seen any other C++11 features that require special build flags, why does this one?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784153/in-g-is-c-11-thread-model-using-pthreads-in-the-background

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945391/stdthread-creation-throws-exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Operation not permitted` exception is thrown in a function called `_M_start_thread` defined in `gcc-4.7.3/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/thread.cc`.

This exception is thrown if a function called `__gthread_active_p` returns a null value. This function is a `C` function defined in `gcc-4.7.3/libgcc/gthr-posix.h`.

This method pokes around in `libc` for the pthread functions and presumably does some funky runtime/lazy binding. Your C++ code links without problem because it doesn't contain any link-time dependency on pthread. C code can tolerate missing link values for functions which it will try to resolve at runtime.

Unfortunately, the C++ sanity checks we normally depend on to catch these issues are bypassed because the pthread linking is done via lazy binding in C code.